# Gitg behavouir as gitk --all

Tags: git, gitk, gitg

I switched to [gitg](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gitg/) from gitk to visualize my git tree. There is one thing I can't stand.

Let's say I have two branches (`dev`, `master`) that look like this:

[image]

Anytime I checkout to `master` the visualization changes:

[image]

That means that the branch I am currently on is on the top of the tree. In other words, I can't see the `dev` branch at the moment.

That is the same default behavouir as `gitk` has, but it can be changed there using `--all` attribute, which makes it the way I want. Can that be achieved using gitg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[That thread](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gitg-list/2012-August/msg00000.html) mentions the possibility to open [`gitg`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gitg/) in "All Branches" mode:

```
gitg -- --all
```

It also mentions that it might not be working in the current version of `gitg` though (the [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=681751) is still unconfirmed)

As the [OP aGr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494468/agr) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700618/gitg-behavouir-as-gitk-all#comment22303941_15702295), there is an option "All branches" in the Branch combo box:

[image: gitg all branches]

But it isn't a persistent choice after a checkout.

Comment: That works for me! I have version 0.2.4 though. As well I noticed a 'all branches' option in the branch selectbox, which I missed before. The thing is that if I checkout somewhere using gitg, the gitg will change the visualisation, so then I have to change the branch in selectbox to 'all branches' againm if I want to. Hm, maybe I am just not used to that behaviour...

Comment: @aGr understood. At least, that command line option is a step in the right direction.

Comment: @aGr I have included the option you mention in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I've been using the gitg with this option for a few days, sometimes I switch to particular branch, where the visualisation is much clearer. I like the behavouir. Thx for your contrubution.

Comment: This does not work for me. As the referenced email indicates, I get "select branch" in the pulldown, and nothing showing in the window (until I select a branch). Version (from Debian 8.2) is 0.2.7-3.

Comment: @liam strange. Since this answer has more than 2 years, you could ask a new question for that more recent behavior.